# C# Form Application int to string error

Tags: c#, forms, if-statement

I am really stuck on this one - I am trying to create an if statement and display the value assigned to the variable in a text box. I keep coming across a "Cannot implicity convert int to string" building error. Thanks.

```
        int n1;
        int userInput = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        if (userInput == 4)
        {
            n1 = 60;

        }
        else if (userInput ==3)
       { 
             n1=40
       }


        {
        textBox2.Text = (n1); //"Cannot implicity convert int to string" 
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have declared `n1` as `int`. The `Text` property of `textBox2` is of type `string`. So you first have to convert `n1` to `string` before you can assign it to the `Text`.

```
textBox2.Text = n1.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks - it also says "there is a use of unassigned local variable n1", but it has been assigned?

Comment: @user1513637 `n1` will be not assigned if `userInput` is not 3 and not 4

Comment: It is only assigned if one of your two if statements is true.

Comment: think what value would n1 be having if the user input is neither 3 nor 4 as in your if conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The error is self explanatory - the compiler cannot convert an integer to a string automagically:

```
textBox2.Text = n1.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `ToString()`

```
textBox2.Text = n1.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert int to string

```
textBox2.Text=n1.TOString();
```

or

```
textBox2.Text=Convert.ToString(n1);
```